# error C3861: 'roundf': identifier not found

Tags: c++

I'm normally good at googling stuff like this but I can't seem to find anything this time.

I downloaded some source code from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Scientific_OpenGL_Tutorial_04) and it uses a function called `roundf`.

I already have `#include <math.h>` and as a first thought added `#include <cmath>` but still have the problem. I can't seem to find out where the function originates...

Is there an alternative function? Or does anyone know where it comes from so I can include the header file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `roundf()` function is defined by C99, but MSVC implements very little of C99, so it is not available with the Microsoft compilers.

You can use this one:

```
float roundf(float x)
{
   return x >= 0.0f ? floorf(x + 0.5f) : ceilf(x - 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why that's better than `float roundf(float x) { return round(x); }`?  This invokes the `double` version (`round()`) on the `float` parameter, which is converted to `double`, of course, and converts the result back to `float`.  Also, if `roundf()` is not available, are `floorf()` and `ceilf()` going to be available?

Comment: You might be right, though I cannot find any documentation about round() in MSVC either, even it being part of C++11. floorf/ceilf is available though.

Comment: `round()` was in C99, along with `roundf()` and `roundl()`.  I assumed, but have yet to verify, that `round()` was in C89/C90 and the other two were added to C99.  _...time passes..._ OK; I've verified that in fact `round()` was not in C89, but plain `ceil()` and `floor()` were.  So, you might need to use those instead of my suggestion. Generally, C89 only had the plain (`double`) versions of the functions, and C99 added the `f`-suffix and `l`-suffix variants.  However, it also added some functions de novo, and `round()` was evidently one such.

Comment: `roundf()` is available as of Visual Studio 2013. [Relevant blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You also can use a boost library:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp>

const double a = boost::math::round(3.45); // = 3.0
const int b = boost::math::iround(3.45); // = 3
```